# EOFException from reading a file

Tags: java, eofexception

The output is correct but it's followed by an *EOFException*. I read the documentation but still i don't know how to solve this

```
try(ObjectInputStream ois = new ObjectInputStream(new FileInputStream("file.bin"))){
    for(Ser s = (Ser)ois.readObject(); s!=null; s=(Ser)ois.readObject() )
        System.out.println(s);
}catch (IOException | ClassNotFoundException e){
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: Once you have read all the objects, stop reading from the ObjectInputStream.  If you don't know how many objects there are, write the count to the ObjectOutputStream before writing the objects to it.  Even easier, if you don't have a huge number of objects, is to write an array.  (Don't write a List;  reading the List would require an unsafe cast.)

Comment: Are you creating `file.bin`? If so, how are you doing that?

Comment: @VGR Reading *anything* from an object stream requires an unsafe cast. Pretending a count isn't always practical, and it is also pointless given that `EOFException` already exists.

Comment: @Fishstick If he wasn't creating it how could he get an `EOFException` reading from it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are assuming that `readObject` returns null if there is no data, but in fact it throws `EOFException`. The simplest fix is just to catch the exception:

```
try(...) {
    for(;;) {
        Ser s = (Ser)ois.readObject();
        System.out.println(s);
    }
} catch(EOFException e) {
    // normal loop termination
} catch(IOException | ClassNotFoundException e){
    // error
}
```

Be aware that some people and coding standards consider it bad practice to have an exception thrown in non-error conditions, like reaching the end of input in this case.

Comment: Which is bad luck, because that is what happens, so they are just going to have to put up with it.